# Error while installing rJava in R console on a windows machine

Tags: r, rjava

I am getting this error while installing rJava package using

install.packages('rJava', type='source', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com')

Warning in system("sh ./configure.win") : 'sh' not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rJava'

Please help in solving this, thanks in advance